# Approximate Logarithmic Function with a Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, logarithm, approximation

I'm trying to approximate a the log-function on  a domain from one to one hundred with a neural network. I use `tensorflow` as software. The results are not as good as I expected and I would like to understand why. I use the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## == data to be approximated == ##
x_grid = np.array([np.linspace(1, 100, 100)]).T
y_grid = np.log(x_grid)


  def deepnn(x_val, prior):
  """
  A neural network with input values x. Its parameters might be constraint according to a prior.
  """
    ## == input layer == ##
    if prior:
        w_in = tf.constant(1., shape=[1, 2]) #fixed to one
        b_in = tf.constant([-1., -20.]) # fixed along kinks of the log function
    else:
        w_in = weight_variable([1, 2])
        b_in = bias_variable([2])
    f_in = tf.matmul(x_val, w_in) + b_in

    ## == first hidden layer == ##
    g_1 = tf.nn.relu(f_in)

    ## == output layer == ##
    w_out = weight_variable([2, 1])
    b_out = bias_variable([1])
    y_predict = tf.matmul(g_1, w_out) + b_out
    return y_predict

def weight_variable(shape):
    """
    generate a weight variable of a given shape
    """
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    """
    generates a bias variable of a given shape
    """
    initial =  tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

x_given = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
y_out = deepnn(x_given, False)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
squared_deltas = tf.square(y_out - y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(50000):
    sess.run(train, {x_given: x_grid, y: y_grid})
print(sess.run(loss, {x_given: x_grid, y: y_grid}))
sess.close()
```

The neural network `deepnn(x_val, prior)` can be of two forms: If `prior` is true, the parameters for the input layer function  `tf.matmul(x_val, w_in) + b_in` are set to `w_in = 1` and `b_in = [-1, -20]`. These values for `b_in` will force the network to have a kink at `x = 20`. If `prior` is false, the parameter values are initialized to random variables for `w` and `b=0.1`. (The values, as well as the computer code, are inspired by a [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros).) The inputs are passed on to a hidden layer with rectifier activation functions and an output layer. Whether the network should adhere to the prior or not is defined in the line `y_out = deepnn(x_given, False)`.

The neural network without prior restrictions produces (almost all the time) inferior results, compared to the network with prior. The network simply resembles a linear function. Curiously, the unrestricted network once produced a very good solution, which I couldn't replicate in subsequent trials though. The results are visualized in the Figure below. [image: Function Approximation with a Neural Network]

Can somebody kindly explain why I cannot train the network well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't check thoroughly your code but it seems that you are not using any non-linear network. Your network is a shallow one (only 1 hidden layer) so to be deep (as you mention in the function) you need more layers. Also, I think you need more nodes in your layer. Try with 2 hidden layers at least.

BTW there is a function that does exactly what is says: [tf.nn.xw_plus_b](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/xw_plus_b)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Do you maybe have an idea why the network I use without strong prior assumption does not train that well though? The estimated parameters of the neural network do not minimize the loss function.